# To check weather string is empty or not

Tags: android

I'm facing a problem to check weather a string is NULL or not in Android. The code is:

```
if (e1.length() == 0)
    Toast.makeText(mainActivity.this, "String is Empty");
```

Comment: What is the problem you are facing?

Answer (score 0):

its pretty easy

you can do that

```
if(e1==null || e1.isEmpty){
     Toast.makeText(mainActivity.this,"String is Empty");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(TextUtils.isEmpty(yourString)){
//it's empty
}
```

Comment: explain a bit / add link to the doc please

Answer (score 0):

Try with below code :

```
if(e1.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
  Toast.makeText(mainActivity.this,"String is Empty");
}
```

Or,

```
String ed_text = e1.getText().toString().trim();

if(ed_text.isEmpty() || ed_text.length() == 0 || ed_text.equals("") || ed_text == null)
{
   Toast.makeText(mainActivity.this,"String is Empty");
}
```